# Can anybody guide me how to get this output from array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

Here i have integer array type as int[]values={1,2,5,4,6,7,55,11,44,71,54,1001}; from this i need to get the duplicated values as 1,11,5,55,4,44.How can i get these values from values array.I tried till now as follows.

```
class duplicateFinder
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
 {      
    int[]values={1,2,5,4,6,7,55,11,44,71,54,1001};
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(values[i]);
    }
 }
}
```

Here what shoud i write the logic so that i can get expected output as:Duplicated values are: 1,11,5,55,4,44.Can anybody help me please.Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: There aren't actually any duplicate value in the array you've given. Why should it print out "1,11,5,55,4,44"?

Comment: I can only think he means repeated digits in a number.. But that would also include 1001.

Comment: And would not include 1...

Comment: You can try this:  `int[]values={1,2,5,4,6,7,55,11,44,71,54,1001};
     for (int k = 0; k < values.length; k++) 
     {
      String val = values[k]+""+values[k];
      for (int i = k+1; i < values.length; i++) 
      {
       String curr = ""+values[i];
       if (curr.equals(val))
       {
        System.out.println(values[k]);
        System.out.println(values[i]);
        continue;
       }
      }
  }`

Comment: @Accollativo,can you add 111,222 to that array and try.Its not working.

Comment: 111 it's not a "duplicate", it's three times 1... It's not so clear what you want...

Comment: @Accollativo,in my question duplicate means number has continiously more than one time that has to print from array.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that :

```
    int[] values = { 1, 2, 5, 4, 6, 7, 55, 11, 44, 71, 54, 1001, 111, 222 };
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        boolean printed = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
            int duplicate = values[i];
            for (int pow = 1 + (int) Math.log10(values[i]); pow <= (int) Math.log10(values[j]); pow++) {
                duplicate += values[i] * (int) Math.pow(10, pow);
            }
            if (values[j] != values[i] && values[j] == duplicate) {
                if (!printed) {
                    System.out.println(values[i]);
                    printed = true;
                }
                System.out.println(values[j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

You can certainly have a better complexity if you sort your array.

Comment: Florent Bayle,can you add 111,222 to that array and try.Its not working.

Comment: @GangadharB Why do you expect 111 and/or 222 to be in the output ? For me, the "duplicate" of 111 would be 111111, not 222.

Comment: Florent,1 is repeated in 111 continiously similarly 2 in repeated in 222 so that is duplicated,array values will be any in numbers.

Comment: Florent Bayle,in my question duplicate means number has continiously more than one time that has to print from array.

Comment: Florent Bayle,thanks for your reply.Have you checked 1 is printing two times.how to restrict that.

Comment: smart solution @FlorentBayle :)